# get subdomain and access folder with it

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have to get the subdomain of my domain (example: **d3strukt0r**.orbitrondev.com/forum.php)
So, of the example i have to get `d3strukt0r` and access the directory: `/service/d3strukt0r/www/forum.php`

This has to work with `.htaccess`

I already tried it with this code:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_SUBDOMAIN} ="" 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]+)\.orbitrondev\.com\.?(:80)?$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /service/%1/www/$1.php [E=SUBDOMAIN:%1,L]
```

what came out was:

> The requested URL /forum.php was not found on this server.

So my code accessed instead of `/service/d3strukt0r/www/forum.php` this `/forum.php`

**EDIT**

It worked with this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]+)\.orbitrondev\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/service/%1/www/$1 -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /service/%1/www/$1 [L]
```

The problem is, when I access a folder `http://d3strukt0r.orbitrondev.com/folder/` it accesses `/folder/` instead of `/service/d3strukt0r/www/folder/`

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: You're maybe trying to access `d3strukt0r.orbitrondev.com/forum.php` instead of `d3strukt0r.orbitrondev.com/forum/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You don't need to set `SUBDOMAIN` env variable since you are checking for existence of `.php` extension anyway
- You cannot match port in `HTTP_HOST` variable
- You should ignore `HTTP_HOST` starting with `www.`

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]+)\.orbitrondev\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/service/%1/www/$1.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /service/%1/www/$1.php [L]
```

Also make sure you're visiting this URL:

```
http://d3strukt0r.orbitrondev.com/forum
```

i.e. without `.php` in the end.

Comment: Wouldn't `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]` break the logic?

Comment: Yes it was a bad copy/paste from question, should have been `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/service/%1/www/$1.php -f [NC]`

Comment: i know, but my problem is just partly solved. read my EDIT message